# Notificationmanager not working on onPostExecute

Tags: android

here is my IncomingCall.java,

It will run when i detect any call is coming in mobile

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String username;
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new AsyncTaskParseJson (context);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Calling ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
 new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
  }


    class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    AsyncTaskParseJson (Context context){

    }
    final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";

    // set your json string url here
    String yourJsonStringUrl =     "http://demo.codeofaninja.com/tutorials/json-example-with-php/index.php";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray dataJsonArr = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            // instantiate our json parser
            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();

            // get json string from url
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);

            // get the array of users
            dataJsonArr = json.getJSONArray("Users");

            // loop through all users
           // for (int i = 0; i < dataJsonArr.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = dataJsonArr.getJSONObject(0);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                firstname = c.getString("firstname");
                lastname = c.getString("lastname");
                username = c.getString("username");

                // show the values in our logcat
                Log.e(TAG, "firstname: " + firstname 
                        + ", lastname: " + lastname
                        + ", username: " + username);

           // }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {


         Log.e("TAG1", "firstname: " + firstname 
                 + ", lastname: " + lastname
                 + ", username: " + username);
         title="hii";
         subject="subject";

         notifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notifyObj = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Notification message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(
                context, NotifyMessage.class), 0);
        notifyObj.setLatestEventInfo(context, title,subject, i);
        notifyObj.number = ++count;
        notifyObj.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notifyObj.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notifyObj.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, notifyObj);

        }
      }

       }
```

this showing me error

context can not be resolved

How to fix this issue ??
i tried to find the issue in internet from last 2 days but still not found any solution.
Please help me

Now i am using this code but getting error

```
  // Invoking the default notification service
          NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);  

          mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Message with explicit intent");
          mBuilder.setContentText("New message from javacodegeeks received");
          mBuilder.setTicker("Explicit: New Message Received!");
          mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

          // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives 
          mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessagesOne);

          // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app 
          Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyMessage.class);
          resultIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationIdOne);

          //This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of the app to Home page
          TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

          // Adds the back stack for the Intent
          stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotifyMessage.class);

          // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
          stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
          PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
             stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT //can only be used once
             );
          // start the activity when the user clicks the notification text
          mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

          myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

          // pass the Notification object to the system 
          myNotificationManager.notify(notificationIdOne, mBuilder.build());
```

here is is the error

The constructor `NotificationCompat.Builder(IncomingCall.AsyncTaskParseJson)` is undefined

The constructor `Intent(IncomingCall.AsyncTaskParseJson, Class<NotifyMessage>)` is undefined

The method create(Context) in the type TaskStackBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (IncomingCall.AsyncTaskParseJson)

The method `getSystemService(String)` is undefined for the type IncomingCall.AsyncTaskParseJson

Comment: I thought Notification is deprecated you should better use NotificationCompat.Builder to build up a Notification. And I really see ne declaration of a context object in your code...only onReceive has one and it gives it to the toast but thats all.

Comment: i have updated the question , please check the error

Comment: check where you want to get the context from!!! Is it from the onReceive() Method? If yes then just keep a reference to this context in your class...what does the error say:"context cannot be resolved to a type?" if yes you know what to do

Comment: the copy and paste code you have added now builds on that this code is inside onReceive method and not outside in a asynctask onPostexecute method....you have no context object in your class to insert

Comment: and do you really have two public classes in one file btw? delete the "public" in your asynctask class!!!Java allows only one public class per file

Comment: yes its saying "context cannot be resolved to a type"

i am running notification on 

 protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {

how to pass context on pustexecute mehtod ??

Comment: yes i have two public class in one file

one is - onReceive and other is  AsyncTaskParseJson

Comment: ok add this constructor to your asynctask class: AsyncTaskParseJson (Context context) plus make a variable in your asynctask to hold this context object then you call it in onReceive like that : new AsyncTaskParseJson (context); and assign the given context reference to your context variable in async class  And you delete the "public" in asynctask class definition

Comment: i made changes in above code but still getting error "context cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: i answered your questioon with code try this out

Answer (score 1):

Here my suggested Code:

```
private class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ...
    Intent intent;
    Context context;
    IncomingCall incomingCall;
    ...
    public AsyncTaskParseJson (Context context,Intent intent,IncomingCall incomingCall)
    {
        this.intent=intent;
        this.context=context;
        this.incomingCall=incomingCall
    }
```

And write in onReceive

```
 new AsyncTaskParseJson(context,intent,this);
```

that will do it i think

Edited it to resolve your issue about this: you need to pass the reference of the BroadcastReceiver class to build up the Pending Intent, the artificial backstack and the Notification

Comment: yes its not showing anymore error but i have to target api minimum 16

what if users api is 10 then my app will not be installed :(

Comment: thats right i had same issue but i didnt need a backstack because didn't want this behaviour just delete the code lines with the TaskStackBuilder. Or search for a solution to use the TaskstackBuilder .. i just gave a f*** about it